# matplotlib set shared axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using matplotlib, it seems the only time to set the `sharex` or `sharey` axis parameters are during sub_plot creation (`add_subplot()`, `subplot()`, `subplots()`).  For an `axes` class there are methods for getting axis sharing (`get_shared_x_axes()`, `get_shared_y_axes()`), but no corresponding methods for setting sharing.  Maybe this is an API oversight, or perhaps it did not fit architecturally.

Is there a way to change the shared axis parameter?

For those that ask why: I'm using a matrix of plots dynamically, and can control this using view limits, but it just seems like there could be an easier way, and turning sharing on/off and using autoscale would be it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is that the way shared axes are set up is to share some of the internal state of the two axes.  It is a tad tricky to get right and the code to do it on-the-fly (both linking and unlinking) doesn't exist in the library yet.

See this [PR](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/1312) for work on-going work on un-linking axes.  Help testing and developing this feature would be appreciated.

Answer (score 25):

Just to mention that a method for sharing axes after their creation does exist by now. For two axes `ax1` and `ax2` you can use

```
ax1.get_shared_x_axes().join(ax1, ax2)
```

See [How share x axis of two subplots after they are created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973223/how-share-x-axis-of-two-subplots-after-they-are-created).

Answer (score 7):

As of [v3.3](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/users/whats_new.html#new-axes-sharex-axes-sharey-methods) there exist the new `Axes.sharex`, `Axes.sharey` methods:

```
ax1.sharex(ax2)
ax1.sharey(ax3)
```