# Is there a way to tie axis of different axes after they are created in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

One can do

```
fig, ax = subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
```

to make axes sharing axis.

I want to tie together different axis of different subplots in a more complicated way, e.g., x-axis of ax1 to ax2, but y-axis of ax2 to ax3 and such.

One way I think is to call `subplot` and use `sharex/sharey` keywords, but this is done at creation.
Is there an object-oriented way to do this in matplotlib after the creation of axes?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a way to do this now.

see:
 - [How share x axis of two subplots after they are created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973223/how-share-x-axis-of-two-subplots-after-they-are-created)
 - [matplotlib set shared axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329292/matplotlib-set-shared-axis)

So your example I think would look something like this:

```
ax1.get_shared_x_axes().join(ax1, ax2)
ax2.get_shared_y_axes().join(ax2, ax3)
```