# How to share x axes of two subplots after they have been created

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

I'm trying to share two subplots axes, but I need to share the x axis after the figure was created. E.g. I create this figure:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(1000)/100.
x = np.sin(2*np.pi*10*t)
y = np.cos(2*np.pi*10*t)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(t,x)
ax2 = plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(t,y)

# some code to share both x axes

plt.show()
```

Instead of the comment I want to insert some code to share both x axes.
How do I do this? There are some relevant sounding attributes
`_shared_x_axes` and `_shared_x_axes` when I check to figure axis (`fig.get_axes()`) but I don't know how to link them.

Answer (score 255, accepted):

The usual way to share axes is to create the shared properties at creation. Either

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
ax2 = plt.subplot(212, sharex = ax1)
```

or

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)
```

Sharing the axes after they have been created should therefore not be necessary.

However if for any reason, you need to **share axes after they have been created** (actually, using a different library which creates some subplots, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718823/aplpy-multiplot-dynamic-axis-sharing) might be a reason), there would still be a solution:

Using

```
ax1.get_shared_x_axes().join(ax1, ax2)
```

creates a link between the two axes, `ax1` and `ax2`. In contrast to the sharing at creation time, you will have to set the xticklabels off manually for one of the axes (in case that is wanted).

A complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t= np.arange(1000)/100.
x = np.sin(2*np.pi*10*t)
y = np.cos(2*np.pi*10*t)

fig=plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
ax2 = plt.subplot(212)

ax1.plot(t,x)
ax2.plot(t,y)

ax1.get_shared_x_axes().join(ax1, ax2)
ax1.set_xticklabels([])
# ax2.autoscale() ## call autoscale if needed

plt.show()
```

---

[The other answer has code for dealing with a list of axes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66126384/52074):

```
axes[0].get_shared_x_axes().join(axes[0], *axes[1:])
```

Comment: The strange reason, by the way, is I saved some figure with pickle and I reload them with another program which looses the sharex property.

Comment: This is useful to connect select subplots.  For example, a figure with 4 subplots: two time series and two histograms.  This allows you to selectively link the time series.

Comment: API docs for the Grouper object: https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/api/cbook_api.html?highlight=grouper#matplotlib.cbook.Grouper.join

Comment: Ohh, I just figured out how to *unshare* an axis (which can be useful in a large grid) - on that axis, do `g = ax.get_shared_y_axes();  g.remove(a) for a in g.get_siblings(ax)]`. Thanks for the starting point!

Comment: Actually, that doesn't remove the shared ticks :(

Comment: @naught101 This Q&A is about sharing the axes. If you have a different problem, you may ask a new question.

Comment: So I ended up using this anyway, because it's an easier way to do a mostly-shared, but not completely shared grid. But I did notice that I had to do the grouping **before** I plotted the data, otherwise the axis scaling would not be identical (each plot would still be zoomed independently). You can see this in your example if you replace the t in the second plot call with `np.arange(1000)/50` - you get the same image, but with different ticks on the x axis (meaning the values for the first plot are completely wrong).

Comment: @naught101 You can just call `ax2.autoscale()`.

Comment: autoscale is really important for me

Comment: This answer really helped me. I was in need of doing so because of having multiple figures, each of which with plots added after they were generated

Comment: Actually, for my old version of Matplotlib, autoscale does not undo the linking.  Anyone know another way to toggle this feature?

Comment: Nice answer! I used the same principle on y-axis. `ax1.set_xticklabels([])` suppressed the ticks which was unwanted. But `ax1.autoscale` was necessary to get ylims update to same values

Comment: The `.join` method ([`matplotlib.cbook.GrouperView.join`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/cbook_api.html#matplotlib.cbook.GrouperView.join)) is deprecated since version 3.6. How would you do without it ?

Comment: @paime If I want ax1 to share its yaxis with ax2 and ax3, i am calling ax2.sharey(ax1), ax3.sharey(ax1)

Answer (score 60):

As of Matplotlib [v3.3](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/users/whats_new.html#new-axes-sharex-axes-sharey-methods) there now exist `Axes.sharex`, `Axes.sharey` methods:

```
ax1.sharex(ax2)
ax1.sharey(ax3)
```

Comment: note: you can only use `Axes.sharex` oncer per object. on the second call it errors out. so if you need to call it more than once use the more complex `Axes.get_shared_x_axes().join()`.

Comment: To get around this issue of only being able to call it once you could instead change the above example by doing what @mins suggested, and "Call ax2.sharey(ax1), ax3.sharey(ax1), and so on if required."

Answer (score 8):

Just to add to ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer above:

If you have an entire `list` of axes objects, you can pass them all at once and have their axes shared by unpacking the list like so:

```
ax_list = [ax1, ax2, ... axn] #< your axes objects 
ax_list[0].get_shared_x_axes().join(ax_list[0], *ax_list)
```

The above will link all of them together. Of course, you can get creative and sub-set your `list` to link only some of them.

**Note:**

In order to have all `axes` linked together, you do have to include the first element of the `axes_list` in the call, despite the fact that you are invoking `.get_shared_x_axes()` on the first element to start with!

So doing this, which would certainly appear logical:

```
ax_list[0].get_shared_x_axes().join(ax_list[0], *ax_list[1:])
```

... will result in linking all `axes` objects together **except** the first one, which will remain entirely independent from the others.

Comment: For everyone having trouble: add "autoscale", if it does not work (see the answers above)

Comment: The `.join` method ([`matplotlib.cbook.GrouperView.join`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/cbook_api.html#matplotlib.cbook.GrouperView.join)) is deprecated since version 3.6. How would you do without it ?

Comment: I can't help I'm afraid as I'm still on an earlier version. But I encourage you to post your solution, if you find one.

Answer (score 3):

Function `join` has been deprecated and will be removed soon. Continuing with this function is not recommended.

You can use the method suggested by [iacob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66789119/774575)
but, as commented by Trevor Boyd Smith, `sharex` and `sharey` can only be called once on the same object.

Thus the solution is to select one single axis as the argument of calls from multiple axes which need to be associated with the first one, e.g. to set the same y-scale for axes `ax1`, `ax2` and `ax3`:

- Select `ax1` as the argument for other calls.
- Call `ax2.sharey(ax1)`, `ax3.sharey(ax1)`, and so on if required.

Comment: Thanks! Currently one cannot make all data points appear with this method, i.e. the previous .join no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `.get_shared_x_axes().join()` method is deprecated, here is a function using `ax.sharex()` that also removes the tick labels of inner plots (as using `sharex=True` at construction time does) and works across figures:

```py
def share_axes(axes, sharex=True, sharey=True):
    if isinstance(axes, np.ndarray):
        axes = axes.flat  # from plt.subplots
    elif isinstance(axes, dict):
        axes = list(axes.values())  # from plt.subplot_mosaic
    else:
        axes = list(axes)
    ax0 = axes[0]
    for ax in axes:
        if sharex:
            ax.sharex(ax0)
            if not ax.get_subplotspec().is_last_row():
                ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False)
        if sharey:
            ax.sharey(ax0)
            if not ax.get_subplotspec().is_first_col():
                ax.tick_params(labelleft=False)
```

Usage:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig1, axes1 = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(3, 3))
fig2, axes2 = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(3, 3))

axes = [*axes1.flat, *axes2.flat]

for ax in axes:
    ax.imshow(np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(10, 10, 3)))

share_axes(axes)

plt.show()
```

[image: Figures with shared axes]