# Pandas and Matplotlib plotting df as subplots with 2 y-axes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a dataframe to a few subplots using pandas and matplotlib.pyplot. But I want to have the two columns use different y axes and have those shared between all subplots.

Currently my code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Area':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C','C','C','D','D','D','D'],
              'Rank':[1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4],
              'Count':[156,65,152,70,114,110,195,92,44,179,129,76],
              'Value':[630,426,312,191,374,109,194,708,236,806,168,812]}
             )
df = df.set_index(['Area', 'Rank'])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))

for i, l in enumerate(['A','B','C','D']):

if i == 0:
    sub1 = fig.add_subplot(141+i)

else:
    sub1 = fig.add_subplot(141+i, sharey=sub1)

df.loc[l].plot(kind='bar', ax=sub1)
```

This produces:

[image: graph output]

This works to plot the 4 graphs side by side which is what I want but both columns use the same y-axis I'd like to have the 'Count' column use a common y-axis on the left and the 'Value' column use a common secondary y-axis on the right.

Can anybody suggest a way to do this? My attempts thus far have lead to each graph having it's own independent y-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a secondary y axis, you can use `twinax = ax.twinx()`. Once can then join those twin axes via the `join` method of an axes `Grouper`, `twinax.get_shared_y_axes().join(twinax1, twinax2)`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973223/how-share-x-axis-of-two-subplots-after-they-are-created) for more details.

The next problem is then to get the two different barplots next to each other. Since I don't think there is a way to do this using the pandas plotting wrappers, one can use a matplotlib bar plot, which allows to specify the bar position quantitatively. The positions of the left bars would then be shifted by the bar width.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Area':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C','C','C','D','D','D','D'],
              'Rank':[1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4],
              'Count':[156,65,152,70,114,110,195,92,44,179,129,76],
              'Value':[630,426,312,191,374,109,194,708,236,806,168,812]}
             )
df = df.set_index(['Area', 'Rank'])

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=len(df.index.levels[0]), figsize=(6,4), sharey=True)
twinaxes = []
for i, l in enumerate(df.index.levels[0]):
    axes[i].bar(df["Count"].loc[l].index.values-0.4,df["Count"].loc[l], width=0.4, align="edge" )
    ax2 = axes[i].twinx()
    twinaxes.append(ax2)
    ax2.bar(df["Value"].loc[l].index.values,df["Value"].loc[l], width=0.4, align="edge", color="C3" )
    ax2.set_xticks(df["Value"].loc[l].index.values)
    ax2.set_xlabel("Rank")


[twinaxes[0].get_shared_y_axes().join(twinaxes[0], ax) for ax in twinaxes[1:]]
[ax.tick_params(labelright=False) for ax in twinaxes[:-1]]

axes[0].set_ylabel("Count")
axes[0].yaxis.label.set_color('C0')
axes[0].tick_params(axis='y', colors='C0')
twinaxes[-1].set_ylabel("Value")
twinaxes[-1].yaxis.label.set_color('C3')
twinaxes[-1].tick_params(axis='y', colors='C3')
twinaxes[0].relim()
twinaxes[0].autoscale_view()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! It's unfortunate that it's not possible to do it more neatly through pandas but this looks great, thank you very much. May I ask what these lines `[twinaxes[0].get_shared_y_axes().join(twinaxes[0], ax) for ax in twinaxes[1:]]
[ax.tick_params(labelright=False) for ax in twinaxes[:-1]]` are you using a list comprehension as a shortened version of a for loop?

Comment: Yep exactly, this is just a shortened version of a for-loop.