# twinx or twinx-like supylabel for matplotlib subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, twinx

Given the subplots setup shown below, is there any possibility to add a super y label at the right side of the plot analogously to the 'Green label'?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True)

axs[0,0].tick_params(axis ='y', labelcolor = 'g')
t = axs[0,0].twinx()
t.tick_params(axis ='y', labelcolor = 'b')

axs[0,1].tick_params(axis ='y', labelcolor = 'g')
axs[0,1].twinx().tick_params(axis ='y', labelcolor = 'b')

axs[1,0].tick_params(axis ='y', labelcolor = 'g')
axs[1,0].twinx().tick_params(axis ='y', labelcolor = 'b')

axs[1,1].tick_params(axis ='y', labelcolor = 'g')
axs[1,1].twinx().tick_params(axis ='y', labelcolor = 'b')


fig.supylabel('Green label', color='g')
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shared secondary axes in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53490960/shared-secondary-axes-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the code in [`fig.supylabel`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/b3bd929cf07ea35479fded8f739126ccc39edd6d/lib/matplotlib/figure.py#L405-L414) I think there is no dedicated function and you will have to resort to the `fig.text` function (which is used internally by `fig.supylabel`).

You can reuse and adapt the defaults of the the `fig.supylabel` function.

Caveats are that you will not have autopositioning and you will have to adjust the rectangle for the `tight_layout`.

```py
...

def supylabel2(fig, s, **kwargs):
    defaults = {
        "x": 0.98,
        "y": 0.5,
        "horizontalalignment": "center",
        "verticalalignment": "center",
        "rotation": "vertical",
        "rotation_mode": "anchor",
        "size": plt.rcParams["figure.labelsize"],  # matplotlib >= 3.6
        "weight": plt.rcParams["figure.labelweight"],  # matplotlib >= 3.6
    }
    kwargs["s"] = s
    # kwargs = defaults | kwargs  # python >= 3.9
    kwargs = {**defaults, **kwargs}
    fig.text(**kwargs)


fig.supylabel("Green label", color="g")
supylabel2(fig, "Blue label", color="b")

fig.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0, 0.96, 1])
plt.show()
```

[image: Resulting plot]

Comment: Thank you! Too bad there seems to be no supylabel-based solution. But this will do.

Comment: Confirmation of answer withdrawn, because the code does not work: figure has no attributes labelsize and labelweight, and | does not  work on dicts

Comment: You need [python 3.9 for dict union](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#dictionary-merge-update-operators) (or change to `defaults.update(kwargs)`), and you need [matplotlib 3.6.0 for `figure.labelsize` and `figure.labelweight`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.6.0.html#allow-setting-figure-label-size-and-weight-globally-and-separately-from-title) (or adapt given code).

Comment: Rather `kwargs = {**defaults, **kwargs}` sorry