# Colorbar for each row in seaborn subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I've looked through similar threads but none of them quite worked for me. What I'm trying to do is display 2x4 heatmaps with a joint colorbar for each row at the end with the same height as the heatmaps.

I create `axes` with 2x5 such that each row has 4 matrices and 1 colorbar axis at the end. The `l2_distances` here is a dictionary with four entries where each key from `MAPPING_DICT` is associated with a matrix (all of same size).

I've figured the best way to do it is to set `cbar=False` for each heatmap I plot and put them into the axes (0-3) while the last heatmap for each row i.e. the one plotted in axis at index `3` plots the colorbar in `cbar_ax=axes[0,4]`.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 MAPPING_DICT = {"P": 0, "A": 1, "C": 2, "S": 3}

 fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,5, sharex=True, sharey=True)
 for env_name in l2_distances:
     l2_dist_matrix = l2_distances[env_name]
     cbar_flag = True if MAPPING_DICT[env_name]==3 else False
     sns.heatmap(l2_dist_matrix, ax=axes[0, MAPPING_DICT[env_name]], linewidths=0.2, square=True, cbar=cbar_flag, cbar_ax=axes[0,4], cmap="Blues", xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False, robust=True)
```

However, this doesn't quite work as the colorbar is plotted at (somewhat) the right spot but without labels and with the wrong height. Here's only the top row of what it looks like (with a few of extra visualization additions which have no effect on the colormap behaviour), the bottom row is basically analogous:
[image: Top row of the 2x5 subplots]

I've played around with explicitly setting the new axes locations but this is rather tedious and doesn't quite work that nice. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Your problem is that `sharex` and `sharey` also affects the colorbars. See [How to unset `sharex` or `sharey` from two axes in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54915124/how-to-unset-sharex-or-sharey-from-two-axes-in-matplotlib) for a way to remove the sharing for the colorbars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that using `sharex=True` and `sharey=True` will give the colorbar the same axes as the rest of the subplots. This messes too much with the colorbar.

[How to unset sharex or sharey from two axes in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54915124/how-to-unset-sharex-or-sharey-from-two-axes-in-matplotlib) shows a way to remove the sharing for the colorbars. This still has some tricky side effects that I couldn't resolve.

The solution below creates the subplots with `sharex=False` and `sharey=False` and then starts sharing all subplots except the colorbars. As the colorbar doesn't need to be as wide as the other subplots, appropriate `width_ratios` can be set.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

MAPPING_DICT = {"P": 0, "A": 1, "C": 2, "S": 3}
l2_distances = {"P": np.random.rand(10, 10), "A": np.random.rand(10, 10), "C": np.random.rand(10, 10),
                "S": np.random.rand(10, 10)}

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=5, sharex=False, sharey=False, figsize=(16, 8),
                         gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [10, 10, 10, 10, 1]})
shax = axes[0, 0].get_shared_x_axes()
shay = axes[0, 0].get_shared_y_axes()
for ax in axes[:, :-1].ravel():
    shax.join(axes[0, 0], ax)
    shay.join(axes[0, 0], ax)
for row in range(axes.shape[0]):
    for env_name in l2_distances:
        l2_dist_matrix = l2_distances[env_name]
        print(env_name, l2_dist_matrix.shape)
        cbar_flag = True if MAPPING_DICT[env_name] == 3 else False
        sns.heatmap(l2_dist_matrix, ax=axes[row, MAPPING_DICT[env_name]], linewidths=0.2, square=True,
                    cbar=cbar_flag, cbar_ax=axes[row, -1], cmap="Blues", xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False,
                    robust=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]