# How to rescale only one y-axis in seaborn catplot and add data labels

Tags: python, seaborn, catplot

I have created a catplot for number of people killed/injured using the catplot function. However, since the scales of the 2 are very different the bars in second graphs are very small and cannot be read. Anyway I can re-scale y-axis of the second chart? And add data labels to both charts?

```
grid = sns.catplot(x = 'borough',
            y = 'Injured/Killed',
            hue = 'Commuter Type',
            col = 'Injury Type',
            data = tabular_breakdown,
            kind = 'bar')
```

[image: catplot output (image)]

Comment: Can you post an example of your plot?

Comment: I just did. It's uploaded as a link below the code snippet

Comment: You might try `sns.catplot(...., sharey=False)`. That way every subplot gets its own separate y-axis.

Answer (score 3):

To solve your issue, there are two things to consider.

1. The call to `catplot` has as the default, `sharey=True`, so whatever you changed in the second axes would reflect on the other.
2. You have to access the two axes in order to adjust them. They are contained in `grid`, so no problem.

To solve the first issue, pass your call with `sharey=False`. To solve the second, access the axes with something like `ax0, ax1 = grid.axes[0]`, then call `ax1.set_ylim(<values>)`. If you don't want to specify `sharey=False`, which is what I was going for initially, you're going to have to resort to the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54915124/how-to-unset-sharex-or-sharey-from-two-axes-in-matplotlib).