# matplotlib.pyplot: sharing axes' x-axis after plotting doesn't put them on the same x-axis limits

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to share matplotlib axes **after** (example axsA) they've been **plotted** (not just after they've been [created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973223/how-share-x-axis-of-two-subplots-after-they-are-created/42974975)). Contrary to my expectation, after doing the join, the axes do not get redrawn with shared xlims, even if I do plt.draw() and plt.show():

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Share two subplot axes AFTER plotting
figA, axsA = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=False)
axsA[0].plot(range(0, 10), range(10))
axsA[1].plot(range(3, 13), range(10))
axsA[0].get_shared_x_axes().join(axsA[0], axsA[1])
figA.suptitle('Join after plotting: x-axes limits are not the same in the two axes.')
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

[image: Join two axes after plotting: x-axes limits are not the same in the two axes.]

I seem able to achieve shared axes only if I join them in a Grouper object **before** plotting:

```
# Share two subplot axes BEFORE plotting
figB, axsB = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=False)
axsB[0].get_shared_x_axes().join(axsB[0], axsB[1])
axsB[0].plot(range(0, 10), range(10))
axsB[1].plot(range(3, 13), range(10))
figB.suptitle('Join after creation, before plotting: x-axes limits are the same oin both axes.')
```

[image: Join two axes after creation, before plotting: x-axes limits are the same oin both axes.]

Is this a bug in matplotlib.pyplot or in my understanding?

Comment: Marking as duplicate, because that linked answer already tells you that you may want to autoscale.

Comment: Aaah, thank you. I glossed past the "you may want to ax.autoscale()" comment in the other answer, not knowing what it was for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ax.get_shared_x_axes().join(ax, ax2)` just appends ax2 to the `Grouper`. You still need to autoscale the axes

```
ax.autoscale()
```

Because both axes are shared now, it is sufficient to autoscale one of the axes.

In the second example it works as expected, because adding a line via `ax.plot` autoscales the axes automatically by default.