# how to share axis just for specific row in subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I just create a subplots using `matplotlib` and choose its parameters as follows:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, 5, hspace=0.1, wspace=0.18, height_ratios=[1, 3])
(ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5), (ax6, ax7, ax8, ax9, ax10) = gs.subplots(sharex='col', sharey='row')
```

Since I choose `sharex='col'` and `sharey='row'`, all plots in the subplots share their x and y axis through columns and rows. Considering my subplot has two rows and five columns, I just want to share x and y axis for the second row, and share the x axis for the first row. The question is I don't want to share y-axis for the first row of the subplot. How to do that?

EDIT:
I tried following, which removes the sharing of the first row.

```
for i in [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5]:
    i._shared_y_axes.remove(i)
```

However now, although I define yticks of the first row they are not shown properly. I mean, for each plot y labels should be shown separately with their ytick values.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share x axes of two subplots after they have been created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973223/how-to-share-x-axes-of-two-subplots-after-they-have-been-created)

Comment: Actually, not totally, I try something (I share in edit part) that remove sharing of the first row of the subplot; however, now the yticks are not seen properly.

Comment: You need to do it the other way, and do all your sharing manually...

Comment: @JodyKlymak what is the other way, creating each axis separately ?

Comment: Its in the link... Create the axes and then `join` lists of axes you want shared.