# Fixed ylabel space (aligned y-axis) across multiple figures

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I'm using code much like:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ['AAA', 'BBBBBBBBBBBBB', 'CCCCCC', 'DDDDDDDDDD']
values = [0, 2, 2, 5]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 0.07 + 0.25 * len(values)))
bars = ax.barh(labels, values, color=colors)
```

to generate horizontal bar plots as separate figures, one after another:

[image: barh]

How can I make the left spines (i.e. the black bars) align when the width of labels varies between plots? (Aside from just aligning the rendered images to the right.)

I think the *left margin/padding/space should be fixed*, or the bar width should be fixed, but I can't quite figure *how* to do it.

Comment: Would using `sharex` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973223/how-to-share-x-axes-of-two-subplots-after-they-have-been-created) be what you are looking for?

Comment: @busybear this works, but requires using a singular figure. I'm afraid I need these to be separate figures.

Comment: `plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)` would set the white space at the left to 20% of the figure width. (If you use `plt.savefig()` you should avoid `bbox_inches='tight'`. In Jupyter, `bbox_inches='tight'` happens automatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these cases, I just add empty axes at the left edge of each figure. I'm sure there are more sophisticated ways, but I find this to be simplest:

- `fig1` with blank axes at `left` location

  ```
  fig1, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 1))
  ax.barh(['AAA', 'BBBBBBBBBBBBB', 'CCCCCC', 'DDDDDDDDDD'], [0, 2, 2, 5])

  # add empty axes at `left` location (unit: fraction of figure width)
  left = -0.05  # requires manual adjustment
  fig1.add_axes([left, 0, 0, 0.01]).axis('off')

  plt.show()
  ```
- `fig2` with blank axes at same `left` location as `fig1`

  ```
  fig2, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 1))
  ax.barh(['AAaaaA', 'BBBB', 'CCCCCC', 'DDDDD'], [2, 8, 7, 1])

  # add empty axes at same `left` location as fig1
  fig2.add_axes([left, 0, 0, 0.01]).axis('off')

  plt.show()
  ```

Output of `fig1` and `fig2`:

[image]

[image]

---

A similar approach would be to `annotate` a space character at the `left` of each figure:

```
ax.annotate(' ', (left, 0), xycoords='axes fraction', annotation_clip=False)
```