# Sharing axes between already created subplots

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I know I can create subplots with a shared axis with something like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax0 = plt.subplot(1,2,1)
ax1 = plt.subplot(1,2,2, sharex=ax0)
```

But, is there any way to share axes after ax1 was created? Something like

```
ax0 = plt.subplot(1,2,1)
ax1 = plt.subplot(1,2,2)

ax1.some_function(sharex=ax0)
```

Comment: what's the context here? why would this be necessary?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329292/matplotlib-set-shared-axis